# MySQL Import & Replace via CSV

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export, csv

I have a MySQL database table named `items` with 10,000+ records. Of these records, I would like to export only records where `item_isbn IS NULL`.

`SELECT * FROM Items WHERE item_isbn IS NULL` produces a table with 500 records, a sample of the data is below;

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| item_id | item_title | item_isbn |
+---------+------------+-----------+
| 1       | Jo         | NULL      |
+---------+------------+-----------+
| 24      | Cars       | NULL      |
+---------+------------+-----------+
| 315     | Fun        | NULL      |
+---------+------------+-----------+
| etc     | etc        | etc       |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

I have exported this table as a CSV file, and have populated it with the necessary ISBNs via MS Excel. I'm now ready to re-import the data into the `itens` table.

How can I re-import these 500 records into the `items` table, whilst overwriting only the same 500 records, and maintaining the same `item_id`.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

I am using PhpMyAdmin.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the rows `where item_isbn IS NULL` and then import the updated CSV file.

While importing, you can disable auto_increment as well in case you're concerned about messing item_id identity.

Answer (score 0):

Imported those records with new temp table and then, write update query based on item_id. this way your item_id is remains same and those records will be updated.

```
UPDATE items i1 INNER JOIN temp_items i2 
ON i1.item_id = i2.item_id 
SET i1.item_title =i2.item_title AND 
i1.item_isbn= i2.item_isbn;
```